# Delphi XE5 Android : how to make each listview item have its own template?

Tags: android, delphi, delphi-xe5

Is there a way to make the TListView of Delphi to behave like actual ListView in android?
for example each item of the list has its own "View" and in that view can be multiple other views(components) like multiple text boxes and check boxes and ...?

[image]

Comment: Your question will get more attention if you attempt to solve this yourself and post what didn't work along with a snippet of code.

Comment: Isn't that how FMX already works?

Comment: Use multiple forms, one for for each activity (view). Activate it when the ListView item is selected, and switch back to the main form when that activity is complete. For an example of switching between forms at runtime, see the FireMonkey Mobile Sample "Forms" located in the Samples folder. You can also use a tab control, and put the ListView on the first tab; selecting an activity activates the appropriate tab page, and when the activity is complete you switch back to the first tab page.

Comment: I am really new to delphi , I don't have any snippet but as i browsed through it i didnt find anything like that. @Ken White : Im not talking about activities (which translates forms) im talking about listviews each item , for example a list of items which each item has 3 texts and 2 checkboxes and these items are sorted underneath eachother and you can scroll through them.hope that clears my question

Comment: @Snaky: Are you talking about ListView groups? You can add group headers and group footers, with list items between them. See the help file for [ListBoxes for mobile](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE5/en/Mobile_Tutorial%3A_Using_ListBox_Components_to_Display_a_Table_View_%28iOS_and_Android%29). There are other FMX mobile tutorials there as well that might be useful.

Comment: @KenWhite Check this image out this is what im talking about : http://i.imgur.com/vYkmIXB.jpg see each item has a big picture and 3 texts , now with that picture in mind , in android you can create as many views as you want for each of listview items and then assign them text , image or ....what i mean is there is a "Template" layout and every listview item follows its rules and fills in the blanks in this case , each list view item fills the picture and the 3 texts.

Comment: The least you could do is be kind enough to post a .png image to reduce the size. :-) Once again, see the tutorial I linked. It shows how to accomplish part of this, and a ListItem in FMX is a container - it can hold images, labels, checkboxes, and just about any other content you want it do hold. There are tutorials for using FireMonkey (non-mobile) that can provide info you can typically use in your iOS/Android apps. Spend some time with those first.

Comment: There are also several ListView samples in the Samples\FireMonkeyMobile\ListView folder. See the `Readme.txt` file in that folder for info on what each one contains.

Comment: Look at the last sample folder I gave you (just above this comment). Open the SampleListViewMultiDetailAppearancePackage.dproj file, right-click it in the Project Manager, and choose "Install". Then File->Close all (save changes), and then open the SampleListViewMultiDetailAppearanceProject.dproj. The first (package) creates the item template and makes it available, the second shows you how to use it.

Comment: Thank you very much,That example is literally the Image that i asked for.

Comment: @Ken Where do multiple forms come into it?

Comment: @David: It doesn't. The poster changed the requirements in the comments and with the addition of the image, and it became clear that something different was being asked than what I commented on. It's fairly clear in the comments above.

Comment: @KenWhite Requirements did not change. Original question described how FMX controls already work.

Comment: @KenWhite in one of your comments you have given an exact answer to the poster's question,you should promote your comment (the one with link) as an answer...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes there is a way. I make it by using these two methods. The CreateItem method is where you put the components you want in the listitem.

```
procedure TForm1.CreateItem;
var
edit1:TClearingEdit;
editCalendar1:TCustomCalendarEdit;
begin
  edit1:= TClearingEdit.Create(Self);
  edit1.Parent := fItem;
  edit1.Align := TAlignLayout.alClient;
  edit1.Text := 'Blabla';
  edit1.OnChange := actEdit1OnChange;

  editCalendar1 := TCalendarEdit.Create(Self);
  editCalendar1.Parent := fItem;
  editCalendar1.Align := TAlignLayout.alRight;
  editCalendar1.Width := 90;
  editCalendar1.Date := Date;
  editCalendar1.OnChange := actEditCalOnChange;
end;

procedure TForm1.CreateListItem;
begin
  fItem:= TListBoxItem.Create(your_listbox);
  fItem.Parent := your_listbox; //Here you put the ListBox as a parent
  fItem.Align := TAlignLayout.alTop;
  fItem.Text := '';
  fItem.Height := 50;

  CreateItem;
end;
```

To add a custom item to the list just call the CreateListItem method! Next to this I use the OnChange method to receive data here is an example:

```
procedure TForm1.actEditCalOnChange(Sender: TObject);
begin
  label1.text := TCalendarEdit(Sender).Text;
end;

procedure TForm1.actEdit1OnChange(Sender: TObject);
begin
  label2.text := TClearingEdit(Sender).Text;
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use TListBox, then you can add list items and each item can have item text and details but you are limited to the predefined layouts. You can not make your completely own layout like in Eclipse. You will have to use FireMonkey Style Designer to create your own style. Take a look [here](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE4/en/Customizing_FireMonkey_Applications_with_Styles).

Comment: Not true, see my answer! You can put every component you want into one TListBox item!