# Most recent dynamically created button is unclickable

Tags: delphi, mobile, dynamic, firemonkey

I'm making a Firemonkey Mobile Application in Delphi XE5 and have a vertical scroll box containing 10 buttons. Text is added by the user, and once all buttons have some text, a new button is created for additional text, using this code:

```
NewButton := TButton.Create(Self);
    with NewButton do
    begin
      Parent := pnlWaiting;
      Height := 40;
      Width := 160;
      Position.X := 20;
      Position.Y := WaitingButtonY;
      TextAlign := TTextAlign(1);
      OnClick := WaitingButtonsClick;
      Text := edtPlayerName.Text;
      Enabled := True;
      Visible := True;
      Name := 'Waiting' + IntToStr(loop);
    end;
    WaitingButtons.AddObject(NewButton.Name, NewButton);
```

The button is created fine, and appears within the vertical scroll box, however is completely unclickable. I added a loop to go through each button contained in the WaitingButtons TStringList, telling me if it was enabled or not, and it does say it is enabled.

Once I add another button, using the exact same code as above, the previous button is suddenly clickable, but the new button is not.

What is causing this?!

Comment: maybe refreshing the pnlWaiting panel would help... just a thought, most likely some bug within the monkey ^_^

Comment: Does `WaitingButtonsClick()` get called when you click the button?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a TAG as an ID of the button. Then when the onClick method is called handle it like so:

```
procedure TForm1.WaitingButtonsClick(Sender: TObject);
var
id:Integer;
begin
  id := TButton(Sender).tag;
end;
```

And check this post for more information how to add components dynamic: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20837752/2728408