# How to dynamically insert/delete items in a TListBox under different headers?

Tags: delphi, listbox, firemonkey, delphi-xe7

I'm working on a multi-platform Firemonkey UI which has some `TListBox` controls which have different headers (`TListBoxGroupHeader`). Each header has a permanent item underneath it to add a new item under that header. The Add Item button is always there at the end of each group after all the items. For example...

- Header 1

  - Item 1
  - Item 2
  - Item 3
  - Add item to Header 1
- Header 2

  - Item 1
  - Item 2
  - Item 3
  - Add item to Header 2
- Header 3

  - Item 1
  - Item 2
  - Item 3
  - Add item to Header 3

The items marked as `Item 1..2..3` are dynamic, while the rest always stay in place in the list. Each item has an object stored in its `Data` property to contain reference information.

How can I manage the dynamic adding/deleting of items within each header of this list as if they're 3 different lists of their own? I was expecting there to be something built-in to Firemonkey to manage this type of scenario, but I have not found anything which controls items between group headers. Only the list as a whole.

Comment: Here you can see how to add items dynamically to a listbox: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20837752/2728408

Comment: And if you want to delete an item use listbox.itemselected then you can delete the selected item by clicking a button or whatever