# ListBox Item Detail causes Text to trim in Firemonkey Delphi XE7

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, listboxitem

This isn't necessarily code-specific, due to the nature of Firemonkey styles.

I have a list of items, each representing a language, and each `TListBoxItem` has its style-lookup set to `listboxitemsrightdetail`.

The detail of the `TListBoxItem` contains the accent of the language, for example `English (US)` or `English (UK)`, where `(US)` and `(UK)` are placed in the detail of the `TListBoxItem`.

So far so good.

**The problem** I am having is that the area or container of the detail item takes up so much space in the `TListBoxItem` that the actual text is trimmed down, basically cut in half followed by three punctuations.

So `English (UK)` is trimmed down to `Engli... (UK)`.

How can I set the detail-container so that it autosizes to its text width?

The problem occurs even if there's plenty of room for the text to be fully visible.

Any ideas?

Comment: The funny thing is that `Engli...` is longer than `English` :P

Comment: @JerryDodge I know right haha

Comment: @JerryDodge longer in terms of number of characters, not necessarily longer in terms of number of pixels required to print it (depending on font selected - ie proportional v non-proportional).

Comment: @Jason you are correct!

Comment: @Jason Indeed, the font used in the code snippets above is the kind where every character is the same width. But the actual product where it's being used might be otherwise.

Comment: Make your own listboxitems! Then you can set all the sizes yourself and align properties and so on!

Comment: @Remi that's what I'm doing. I create my `TListBoxItem` by code, not by IDE editor.

Answer (score 0):

Try to make your own ListboxItem using labels and layouts. And don't set the listboxitem text or detail. An example on how to do this: [Custom ListboxItem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20837752/2728408)